# TTS speech from console

Tags: command-line, voice-command, text-to-speech

Can I synthesize arbitrary text strings with TTS from the Android's console?

To give the idea, on Debian I would do:

```
festival --tts <(echo Buongiorno signore)
```

The TTS engine needs to be always available and run offline, thus Google TTS is not an option. The phone is a "*Samsung Galaxy Fame gt-s6810p*" with Android 4.1.2; it comes with an offline Samsung TTS engine installed.

Answer (score 1):

I normally run android tts from android terminal, just the way on linux.

I achieve this with [sl4a](https://github.com/kuri65536/sl4a/releases) & Python4Android (github.com/kuri65536/python-for-android/releases). 
[Here](http://txt.do/524sz) is the wrapper script that I use for python environment in terminal.

Just Create a python program using sl4a tts api, like this ::

```
`#!/system/bin/py  # Change the Path to wrapper script

 import android
 import sys

 droid = android.Android()

 print 'Speaking ::' + sys.argv[1]
 droid.ttsSpeak(sys.argv[1])
```

`

Save as tts. Run it in terminal with your text as argument.

```
tts 'Hello, It's me TTS , running from console.'
```